# Why getting a Fatal Error by calling $this->title from grandparent class?

Tags: php

In our old project there is a code likes this:

```
class X {
var title = "";
}


class Y extends X {
    echo $this->title;
}


class Z extends Y {

    function printTitle(){
        echo "<b>".$this->title."</b>;
    }
}
```

In PHP 5.4 it works fine, but today I install PHP7.0.3 on the server and started to Test the application.

And now I am facing to this error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in ...
```

I've absolutely no idea why this should produce this fatal error.

How can I fix it?

Comment: you can't use commands directly inside a class. you have to wrap-it in methods

Comment: @fusion3k thank you for the fast reply, but can you give me a explanation who and why? I don't understand why it works with PHP5.3 and not with PHP7. Currently I read on the PHP.net the article 'Backward incompatible changes'

Comment: Sure you paste code correctly? Code above doesn't work in **all** php version (See [here](http://goo.gl/RYRqhI)). Also, the error is not “Using $this->...” but “syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO”. Please edit post with correct code and exact line which produce error! Also in class X definition there is a typo!

Comment: No, it didn't works fine on any version of PHP,..and you forget **$** for title

Comment: @fusion3k thank you.. now I use `trait` to fix it.. now it works. Thank you for the time and explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class X {
    private $title;

    public function __construct($title){
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    public function getTitle() {
        return $this->title;
    }
}


class Y extends X {
}


class Z extends Y {

    public function printTitle(){
        echo "<b>".$this->getTitle()."</b>;
    }
}


$z = new Z("My title");
$z->printTitle(); //echo "<b>My title</b>"
$z->getTitle(); //Returns "My title"
```